# Combine JSON Data onto one jquery variable

Tags: jquery, json

so I am able to get two separate JSON requests and spit out the data separately. What I cannot figure out is how to combine the data from one JSON array to the other. Below is the JS that calls both JSON arrays, the idea is to be able to match the dates from both arrays and spit out the goal data (conversions, completions, value) on each day on the calendar. All of the data should be added to the citationHTML variable.

```
        var zipcode = '27560';
    var appid = '96afa96cadeb7165258ae95b77fdc';
    var startdate = '2015-09-01';
    var enddate = '2015-09-30';
    var timeperiod ='24';           

    var dataUrl = '//api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/past-weather.ashx?q='+ zipcode +'&format=json&date='+ startdate +'&enddate='+ enddate +'&tp='+ timeperiod +'&key='+ appid    

    var dataUrl2 = '//westbrookfl.com/wp-content/plugins/CSAnalytics/lib/data/data-GoalValueTotals.php'

    //Creates Table for Citation Data       
        $.when(
            $.getJSON(dataUrl),
            $.getJSON(dataUrl2)
        ).done (function (data, data2) {
            var data = data[0].data;
            console.log(data, data2);
            var citationHTML = '';
            var channelHTML = '';
            jQuery.each(data, function (i) {
            var weather = data.weather;
                for (var i = 0; i < weather.length; ++i) {
                    citationHTML += '<li id="day'+[i]+'" class="day"><div class="date">' + weather[i].date + '</div><div class="svg-icon"><img src="' + weather[i].hourly[0].weatherIconUrl[0].value + '" /></div><div class="data-wrap col2"><p class="data hi-temp"><span>' + weather[i].maxtempF + '</span><sup class="deg ng-scope" data-ng-if="hasValue()">°</sup></p><p class="data lo-temp"><span>' + weather[i].mintempF + '</span><sup class="deg ng-scope" data-ng-if="hasValue()">°</sup></p></div><p class="data desc">' + weather[i].hourly[0].weatherDesc[0].value + '</p></li>';
                }
            })
            jQuery.each(data2[0], function (i, item) {                  
                channelHTML += '<tr><td class="tg-yw4l">' + item.date + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + (+item.goalConversionRateAll).toFixed(2) + '%</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + item.goalCompletionsAll + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">$' + item.goalvalueall + '</td></tr>';
            })
            jQuery('#citation_report').append(citationHTML);
            jQuery('#channeldata_table').append(channelHTML);
        });
```

Here is fiddle for it as well: https://jsfiddle.net/joseph_a_garcia/s41kr5hj/52/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looping your first array, you need to store a lookup value that can be used in your second loop.

Create a lookup object, then in your first loop:

```
var key = weather[i].date.replace(/-/g,'')
lookup[key] = i;
```

Then use that object in the second loop to find the matching item. Here's your code re-written:

```
$.when(
    $.getJSON(dataUrl),
    $.getJSON(dataUrl2)
).done (function (data, data2) {
    var data = data[0].data;
    console.log(data, data2);
    var citationHTML = '';
    var channelHTML = '';
    var lookup = {};
    var weather = data.weather;
    for (var i = 0; i < weather.length; ++i) {
        var key = weather[i].date.replace(/-/g,'');
        lookup[key] = i;
        citationHTML += '<li id="day'+[i]+'" class="day"><div class="date">' + weather[i].date + '</div><div class="svg-icon"><img src="' + weather[i].hourly[0].weatherIconUrl[0].value + '" /></div><div class="data-wrap col2"><p class="data hi-temp"><span>' + weather[i].maxtempF + '</span><sup class="deg ng-scope" data-ng-if="hasValue()">°</sup></p><p class="data lo-temp"><span>' + weather[i].mintempF + '</span><sup class="deg ng-scope" data-ng-if="hasValue()">°</sup></p></div><p class="data desc">' + weather[i].hourly[0].weatherDesc[0].value + '</p></li>';
    }
    jQuery('#citation_report').append(citationHTML);
    jQuery.each(data2[0], function (i, item) {
        var day = $("#day" + lookup[item.date]);
        day.append('<tr><td class="tg-yw4l">' + item.date + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + (+item.goalConversionRateAll).toFixed(2) + '%</td><td class="tg-yw4l">' + item.goalCompletionsAll + '</td><td class="tg-yw4l">$' + item.goalvalueall + '</td></tr>');
    })
});
```

Here's a fixed fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s41kr5hj/54/

Comment: Thanks @Dave The fiddle looks good, except the data looks duplicated in the results box. Am i missing something?

Comment: You shouldn't be looping over `data` just loop the `data.weather` contents. I updated the answer and the fiddle.